How to handle path traversal vulnerability in webpack-dev-middleware with Vue CLI dependency constraints?
I'm dealing with a security vulnerability in webpack-dev-middleware reported as CVE-2024-29180, which involves insufficient URL validation that allows path traversal attacks. Dependabot flagged this issue but cannot update webpack-dev-middleware to a non-vulnerable version due to conflicting dependencies in my project that uses Vue CLI.
The specific conflict arises because @vue/cli-service@4.5.19 requires webpack-dev-middleware@^3.7.2 via webpack-dev-server@3.11.3, and the fixed version for the vulnerability starts from 5.3.4.
Given this dependency chain, updating to a secure version seems non-trivial. Here’s more detail on the vulnerability:

Affected versions: <= 5.3.3
Patched version: 5.3.4

Questions:

How can I safely update webpack-dev-middleware in a project that depends on @vue/cli-service@4.5.19?
Is there a workaround to mitigate this vulnerability without upgrading the entire Vue CLI or webpack stack?
Can anyone suggest best practices for configuring devServer or devMiddleware to prevent such vulnerabilities in future setups?


I resolved this issue by simply upgrading the webpack-dev-middleware package.
It suggests that the package is vulnerable below or equal to the 5.3.3 version.
npm install webpack-dev-middleware@5.3.4 -D

And put the package to the overrides in package.json

NOTE: After adding this please delete node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstall
